# How to use GTFS-realtime in OpenTripPlanner standalone?

Tags: protocol-buffers, gtfs, opentripplanner

I developed a tool to convert german transit data into GTFS and GTFS-realtime.

Now I've got the task to test these files in OTP and I installed this standalone Version:

https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/Minimal-Introduction

Everything works fine with my GTFS Data, but now I'm totally lost when it comes to using my GTFS-realtime Data. How can I include them? Is it even possible in the standalone Version?

Sorry if these are totally stupid questions but I'm a rookie in OTP and I appreciate any help or hint :)

Comment: what is the data format of the transit data you are converting into GTFS and GTFS-realtime ?

Comment: please which tool did you use to convert the data into GTFS, i guess you are refer to HAFAS as the german transit data

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java demo that consume a GTFS-realtime data.

https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-visualizer/wiki

Take a look at "digging into the code" section.

All the mentioned entities such as FeedMessage, Vehicle, ..., etc. is generated from GTFS-realtime.proto via

protoc GTFS-realtime.proto --java_out=

You will need to download, make install the Protocol buffer tool(protoc)